# How do I make the rig on the right deform the mesh like the rig on the left?

Tags: rigging

Can anyone tell me what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

[image: Example]

[BLEND FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/145cymAEMZMk8wafRGlaUhjPT_v_GodvJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to take the two meshes into weight paint mode and compare how they are painted.  The one on the right needs adjustments.

Comment: From your blend file I see that the rig on the left is using [corrective shapekeys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/corrective_shape_keys.html) to overcome the limits of the weight painting.  You'll need to learn how to do that and then apply the technique to the rig on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the left rig, unfortunately, the option `[X] Deform` is activated for almost every bone, even if it is only a control or mechanic bone.

So you need to check the vertex group of the mesh to figure out which bones actually deform the mesh.

As you can see in the screenshot the right arm is deformed by the bones *R.arm, R.arm_elbow* and *R.wrist_target2*. But if you look at the rig there is only *R.wrist* visible and no *R.wrist_target2*.

[image: vertex groups of the bones]

After inspecting the bones layers further you will find this *R.wrist_target2* bone on bone layer 3. For a better overview you can add it to layer 1 (in *Edit* mode select the bone and press <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the first layer)

Now it's clear why the hand deforms differently compared to the rig on the right where the *Down* bone (= wrist bone) is not a control bone but a deformation bone.

If you want to make your rig work the same you need to add another bone at the position of *R.wrist_target2* and make it a deformation bone. Then make the *Down* bone a control bone that rotates the wrist target bone.

[image: deform bones]

As mentioned in the comments, the elbow bone triggers a shapekey (*Bend*) with help of a driver to keep a blocky elbow shape.